# How do I make this SQL statement return empty strings instead of NULLS?

Tags: sql, null

```
LastAccessed=(select max(modifydate) from scormtrackings WHERE 
bundleid=@bundleid and userid=u.userid),
CompletedLessons=(select Value from scormtrackings WHERE 
bundleid=@bundleid and userid=u.userid AND param='vegas2.progress'),
TotalLessons=100,
TotalNumAvail=100,
TotalNumCorrect=(SELECT Value FROM scormtrackings WHERE 
bundleid=@bundleid AND userid=u.userid AND param='cmi.score.raw')
```

This is only part of a large select statement used by my ASP.NET `Repeater` that keeps crashing when the values are `NULL`, I have tried `ISNULL()` but either it didn't work, or I did it wrong.

```
ISNULL((SELECT max(modifydate) FROM scormtrackings WHERE 
bundleid=@bundleid AND userid=u.userid),'') AS LastAccessed,
```

*(...)*

???

UPDATE: I've tried all these things with returning '', 0, 1, instead of the value that would be null and it still doesn't work, I wonder if the problem is with the `Repeater`?

#### Related Question:

> [Why does my repeater keep crashing on Eval(NULL) values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584570/why-does-my-repeater-keep-crashing-on-evalnull-values)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the [COALESCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) function to avoid getting nulls.  Basically it returns the first non-null value from the list.

```
SELECT COALESCE(dateField, '') FROM Some_Table
```

This is an ANSI standard, though I have noticed that it isn't available in Access SQL.

Comment: COALESCE is actually ANSI SQL. It's not a vendor extension.

Comment: @derobert Thanks, I updated the answer to reflect your comment.

Answer (score 3):

You can use CASE:

```
CASE WHEN MyField IS Null THEN ''
ELSE MyField
End As MyField
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select max(isnull(modifydate, "default date") from scormtrackings where...
```

will work as long as there is at least one row that satisfies the where clause, otherwise you will still get NULL

```
select IsNull( max(modifydate), "default_date") from scormtrackings where ...
```

should work in all cases

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NVL`.

`NVL(<possible null value>,<value to return when arg1 is null>)`

Answer (score 0):

```
select max(isnull(Date,"default date")) .....
```

Answer (score 0):

This works too... hate to admit how often I use it!!

Declare @LastAccessed varchar(30)

Select @LastAccessed = max(modifydate) from scormtrackings

Set @LastAccessed = isnull(@LastAccessed,'')

Select @LastAccessed as LastAccessed

Comment: You can do it in single select as well: Select @LastAccessed = max(modifydate), @LastAccessed = isnull(@LastAccessed,'') from scormtrackings